# lx-symbols: Python Exception <class 'gdb.MemoryError'> Cannot access memory at address 0xff

Tags: linux-kernel, gdb, remote-debugging

I'm trying to load the **lx-symbols** from the kernel. but it keeps showing me the following error:

```
(gdb) lx-symbols
loading vmlinux
Python Exception <class 'gdb.MemoryError'> Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffff824fb470: 
Error occurred in Python command: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffff824fb470
```

Now I was successfully able to load the **lx-symbols** before from the same build(not sure if this is the correct terminology) but don't know why I can load it anymore.

Now, When I first connect to the remote machine via gdb it used to shows the build trace like the following:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3.2) 8.1.0.20180409-git
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./vmlinux...done.
(gdb) target remote: 1235
Remote debugging using : 1235
native_safe_halt ()
    at /build/linux-hwe-22QmxS/linux-hwe-5.3.0/arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h:61
61    /build/linux-hwe-22QmxS/linux-hwe-5.3.0/arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h: No such file or directory.
```

Now when I connect to the remote kernel, it is showing me just this :

```
(gdb) target remote :1235
Remote debugging using :1235
0xffffffff81a98522 in __irqentry_text_end ()
```

I notice that the build trace  **/build/linux-hwe-22QmxS/linux-hwe-5.3.0/arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h:61
61** disappear (I did not make any changes to the configuration or setting).

This is the **second time** I'm facing the same problem. At the first time, I thought maybe i accidentally make some changes but as the problem occurs again, this time I'm quite sure I did not make any changes.

I have my **.gdbinit** file with the correct path.

```
add-auto-load-safe-path /../../ubuntu-bionic/debian/build/build-generic/vmlinux-gdb.py
```

I checked if the source is loading correctly by using the this:

```
(gdb) source /home/../../ubuntu-bionic/debian/build/build-generic/vmlinux-gdb.py
```

It didn't throw me any error. So, I guess the source is loading correctly. I just don't know what else to do. Please help.

Comment: I have the same problem with kernel 4.19.101 from kernel.org build with bebug symbols.

Comment: @AlekseyM Did you find any solution? The only way I can get around is by installing and configuring a new VM

Comment: I installed the latest kernel 5.5 and it worked properly. Still trying to make it work on this kernel.

Comment: @AlekseyM I mean, it works for me too. But after some time, it stops working. As I mentioned in the post, the build trace disappears. And once it does that,  loading `lx-symbols` stop working and throws the above error.

Comment: You may check that in your linux kernel build directory there exist proper symlink
```vmlinux-gdb.py -> scripts/gdb/vmlinux-gdb.py```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add to the kernel boot parameters "nokaslr" and/or build with CONFIG_RANDOMIZE_BASE=n